# PHP command-line: efficient way to parse arguments in a form of commands, subcommands, and parameters

Tags: php

I have a script that should be called as follow:

```
script.php command subcommand --parameters parameter1="a" parameter2="b" parameterN="n"
```

Example:

```
script.php account backup import --parameters accont="UserA" backup_id=1
```

Where `command = 'account'`, `subcommand = 'backup import'`, and `parameters = 'account="UserA"'  backup_id=1`

- Each command can have multiple subcommands.
- And each subcommand accepts **only** specific parameters (some mandatory, and some optional).

Is there an efficient way to parse all the cases without having 4-level nested switch?

Thank you.

--- information added to complete the question ----
This is how it'd look:

```
// command stack
$commands = array('group', 'account', 'context');

// subcommand stack
$group_subcommands = array(
    'get',
    'list',
);
$account_subcommands = array(
    'add',
    'backup import',
    'backup list',
    'mfa add',
    'mfa del',
    'mfa list',
    'del',
    'get',
    'list',
    'register',
    'set',
    'antivirus get',
    'antivirus set',
);
$context_subcomands = array(
    'list',
);
```

Example unique arguments for each subcommand:

```
account add --parameters account="user1" name="John" last_name="Smith" --city="London"
```

**mandatory** = account, name, last_name
**optional** = city

```
account del --parameters accont="UserA"
```

**mandatory** = account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your commands/subcommands like this:

```
$commands = ['group', 'account', 'context'];
$subCommands = [
  'group' => ['get', 'list'],
  'account' => ['add', 'backup import', 'backup list', 'mfa add', 'mfa del', 'mfa list', 'del', 'get', 'list', 'register', 'set', 'antivirus get', 'antivirus set'],
  'context' => ['list']
];
```

and make use of the following function:

```
function parseCommand(string $commandLine): array
{
  // Should ideally not be stored here, but somewhere like a config file, or at least in constants
  $commands = ['group', 'account', 'context'];
  $subCommands = [
    'group' => ['get', 'list'],
    'account' => ['add', 'backup import', 'backup list', 'mfa add', 'mfa del', 'mfa list', 'del', 'get', 'list', 'register', 'set', 'antivirus get', 'antivirus set'],
    'context' => ['list']
  ];

  if (!preg_match('/^(?<command>\w+)\s+(?<subCommand>[\w\s]+)(?:\s+--parameters\s+(?<paramsString>.*))?$/', $commandLine, $commandMatches)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid syntax.');
  }

  if (!in_array($commandMatches['command'], $commands, true)
      || !in_array($commandMatches['subCommand'], $subCommands[$commandMatches['command']], true)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid command and/or subcommand.');
  }

  $subCommandParams = [];
  if (!empty($commandMatches['paramsString'] && preg_match_all('/(?<name>\w+)=(?:"(?<value1>[^"]*)"|(?<value2>\w*))"?/', $commandMatches['paramsString'], $paramsMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER))) {
    foreach ($paramsMatches as $paramMatch) {
      $subCommandParams[$paramMatch['name']] = $paramMatch['value1'] ?: $paramMatch['value2'];
    }
  }

  return [$commandMatches['command'], $commandMatches['subCommand'], $subCommandParams];
}
```

I didn't add anything for optional/mandatory params but this should be easy enough to implement.

Also, ideally you should use classes to hold commands / subcommands and probably also return a dedicated object from the function (instead of an array).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/aJopL**

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have a couple of points that I don't see how to make it work:
1. double quoted arguments are not properly read. Ex: last_name="Smith Parker", just shows `[last_name] => Smith`.
2. I can pass any word as command, or subcommand, that is not validated (as it would happen with a switch).
3. Could you please tell me a bit more about using a class and returning an object? Thanks.

Comment: @jmox See my updated answer / demo link. I adjusted the regexp to allow spaces (and actually anything) within double quotes. Also added a check for invalid commands/subcommands based on the defined array (that I forgot about). Is that better?